# Appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs

When doing an npm update with npm audit fix --force I started getting this build output:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (20:40) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type. | var seeLocation =
> function seeLocation(lat, long) { |   var link =
> "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + lat + "%2C" +
> long;
>
> > var win = window.open(link, '_blank')?.focus(); | }; |

This is the code:

```
const seeLocation = ( lat:any, long:any) =>{

    const link="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="+lat+"%2C"+long
    const win= window.open(   link, '_blank')?.focus();

  }
```

What does it means: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

This is how I call the function:

```
<IonCol id="ioncol-homeclient"  onClick={() => seeLocation(props.data.lat, props.data.long) }   >
  <IonRow id="ionrow-homecliente">
  <IonIcon icon={location} /> </IonRow>
  <IonRow id="ionrow-homeclient"><small>SEE LOCATION</small></IonRow>
</IonCol>
```

Comment: probably there's more to your code that you're showing, cause you don't need a loader for a link, which isn't even a dynamic import.

Comment: But what's a loader? I alredy edit and post where I call the function.

Comment: a loader in this case would be a library that handles (parses and outputs something) a specific file type

Comment: Thanks @Joshua but what files? because there is not file, there is a link. Also, could you please share an example?